# Export button on highcharts to open new tab

Tags: javascript, zend-framework, highcharts

I have a rendered chart on a page and I am overwriting the high charts export link to a custom link to be used with a Zend view.

I am new to javascript and I'm not sure how to export to the new tab:

```
data.chartOptions.exporting.buttons.printButton = {
                    onclick : function() {

                        var win=window.open('','','location=0,titlebar=0,status=0,width=780,height=350');
                        win.focus();
                        this.exportChart({
                            url: ***.zendLink({
                                param1:***,
                                param2:***,
                                controller:"spm",
                                id:data.id,
                                action:"view",
                                format:"print"
                            })
                        });
                    }

                }
```

This does not seem to work, The window is opened and the link is followed on the first window, eg not in the new window. How do I do this?

Do I need to load the javascript into the new window?

If you would like any more information please ask. I'm not sure how much of the code you require.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing those as two different things.
1) Opening an window.
2) Calling exportChart.

You should open a some page in you site and render the chart there. So should load export chart source also for that.

You can open a window in new tab like this

```
window.open('http://www.google.com', '_blank', 'toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=0');
```

But, it opens an URL in a new tab.

You should have a chart script in that page, and on load of that page you should call this method

```
this.exportChart
```

Comment: That will work even though the chart is actually rendered on a different page?

Comment: Hm. I already show the chart. In this new window I'm redirecting to my zend view where I want the svg data, to convert to png and src it in the page. Essentially all I need is the svg data which highcharts exports, I don't really want to show the chart again and then redirect...

Comment: ok in that case, you can collect the svg data in the URL specified..if it sends ajax request, then after callback is fired, redirect the page using javscript

Comment: Glad to know that you fixed it!